# After pressing the button in qt it opens many windows instead of opening one one

Tags: c++, qt

I'm writing the part of the code which recognizes the collision and checks if the health is more than 3, if it is less than 0, then a that window and all the processes should be stopped and "game over" window should be opened. Everything works the right way, but instead of opening one "game over" window it keeps opening many of them. I don't really understand what's the problem since I closed the view window. Here is that part of the code:

```
void Cactus::move()
{
    //getting a list of all the cactuses currently coliding with the object
QList<QGraphicsItem*>colliding_items=collidingItems();

// if one of the colliding items is a cactus, then destroy both the object and the cactus
    for (int i = 0, n = colliding_items.size(); i < n; ++i)
    {
        if (typeid(*(colliding_items[i])) == typeid(GraphicsActor))
        {
            //check if the health is greater than 0
            if(view->health.getHealth()>0)
            {
            //decrease the health
            view->health.decrease();
            // remove the cactus
            scene()->removeItem(this);
            // delete the cactus from the heap
            delete this;
            return;
            }
            //if the health is smaller than 0
           else
            {
                //if the score you got is greater than the best score before
                if(view->score.getScore()>view->score.getBestScore())
                {
                    //assign the current score to the best score
                    view->score.assignBest();
                }
                 scene()->removeItem(this);
                delete this;
               view->setFinished(true);
                //close the game
                view->close();
                //open gameOver window
                GameOver window1;
                window1.exec();
            }
        }
    }
    //move cactus down
    setPos(x(),y()+5);
    //delete the cactus when it goes out of the screen
    if(pos().y()>400)
    {
        scene()->removeItem(this);
        delete this;
    }
}
```

Comment: `delete this` is almost always a bad idea. After that, whoever called your function has a zombie cactus on their hands.

Comment: well, with or without "delete this" nothing changes

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger to step through your code and see what is actually going on?

Comment: you can try `return`ing after calling `exec` to check if there are many colliding items, but as Mat said it's better to rethink your design, your ui and logic code are very tightly coupled